# Import TensorFlowLite in swift code(no such module error)

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, bazel, tensorflow-lite

I want to add the TensorFlowLite framework to my xcode project.
To do this, I did the following:

1)`pod init` in project directory 
2) in podfile add `pod 'TensorFlowLiteSwift'` in my target 
3) `pod install` 
get warning: 
*[!] The mediapipe-examples-ios-handtrackinggpu-HandTrackingGpuAppLibrary [__TulsiTestRunner_Debug] target overrides the GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS build setting defined in Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-mediapipe-examples-ios-handtrackinggpu-HandTrackingGpuAppLibrary/Pods-mediapipe-examples-ios-handtrackinggpu-HandTrackingGpuAppLibrary.__tulsitestrunner_debug.xcconfig. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the $(inherited) flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.* 
4) building a project with bazel without errors 
5) after `import TensorFlowLite` in .swift file get error `no such module 'TensorFlowLite'`